# MySQL update table with nested select

Tags: mysql, sql, select, nested, sql-update

I have a MySQL table called `portfolio` it has the following columns: `period varchar(10)`, `fbAdjustedClose double`, `fbCumulativeReturn double`

I need to update the fbCumulativeReturn based on the very first entry. This works in getting that record:

```
select *
from portfolio
order by period asc
LIMIT 1;
```

Now, I need to update EVERY row, by setting the `fbCumulativeReturn` equal to `fbAdjustedClose` divided by the `fbAdjustedClose` from the first entry that I selected above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE portfolio p
, (SELECT fbAdjustedClose FROM portfolio ORDER BY period LIMIT 1) q
SET p.fbCumulativeReturn = q.fbAdjustedClose;
```